# Get points of user that is currently logged in from realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the points and show to the owner of that account when he is logged in I tried reading firebase documentation but I couldn't made it here is the code that I use for assigning the random key and saving the child data

```
const autoid = firebase.database().ref("user").push().key;
firebase.database().ref("user").child(autoid).set({
  Email :email,
  Password : password,
  Points :"500"
});
```

[image: Picture of database]

I want whenever the user is login get his points from database and show it on their profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are generating a random key and then assigning it to a variable. A better way to do is to get the `userId` and assign it as a `documentid` and then when retrieving the data use the `userId` to get the user's data.

For example, to add the data:

```js
const database = firebase.database();
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
if (user !== null) {
  // Add user data in collection "users"
 database.ref("users").child(user.uid).set({
    email :email,
    password : password,
    points :"500"
   })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("data successfully written!");
   })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error writing data: ", error);
  });
}
```

Then after the user logins in, you can do the following to retrieve `points`:

```js
const database = firebase.database();
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
if (user !== null) {
  let ref = database.ref("users").child(user.uid);
  ref.get().then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        console.log("data:", snapshot.val());
        console.log(snapshot.val().points);
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting data:", error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I describe doc and db collection in the form of firebase.database

Comment: @GaitoUchiha check edit

Comment: Do I need to change rules for getting uid?

Comment: Are you using firebase Auth?

Comment: Yes I am using firebase Auth

Comment: What are you getting now? The rules are only for the database, if the user is returning null then the user is not authenticated

Comment: I want to get uid of user while creating an account and retrieve data at firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged

Comment: `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    var uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});`

Comment: No any extra rules nedded for database?

Comment: Depends how you structured the database check: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security

Comment: OK will try your above method

Comment: Anyway you can give me the solution for question I stated, I am getting some problems with your code

Answer (score 0):

I can show you how to do it in java just adjust it to your kotlyn code:
Define the reference you want to listen to(above the onCreate):

```
 FirebaseDatabase FBDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
 
 DatabaseReference refUsers=FBDB.getReference("Users");
 FirebaseUser user;


@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);               
      user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()

refUsers.child(user.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new 
 ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                customer = dataSnapshot.getValue(Customer.class);
                int points = customer.getPoints();
                ShowPoints();
       });
    }


}
```

Comment: Does getUid() gets the push key or?

Comment: When user has autenticated to your app you can get his uid by: user.getUid();                       uid is User identifier (Unix), a code identifying each user.

Comment: I didn't understood your code 100% but I was able to get some ideas and I was able to get the push key but wasn't able to get the points

Comment: If your user object that you defined getPoints(); use it inside the SingeValueEvent Listener and write a code that shows  it to the user inside that listener.

Comment: Can you write it on javascript